# Why isn't my else working?

Tags: php, if-statement, upload

```
if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']))
{
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],$uploaddir.'/'.$_FILES['file']['name']);
}
print "Your file was successfully uploaded!";
} else { (This is my error.)
print "Incorrect file extension!";
}
```

Why doesn't the else work? 
I can't seem to figure it out by myself, so I decided to ask someone who has more knowledge of php than I do.

Comment: Looks like some brackets are mismatched to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a closing brace to many:

```
if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']))
{
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],$uploaddir.'/'.$_FILES['file']['name']);
    print "Your file was successfully uploaded!";
} 
else 
{ 
  print "Incorrect file extension!";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That is because

- Your **`print`** statement was inbetween of **`if`** and **`else`** statements.
- You had an extra brace.

Here's the fixed code.

```
<?php
if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']))
{
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],$uploaddir.'/'.$_FILES['file']['name']);
    print "Your file was successfully uploaded!";
}
else
{
print "Incorrect file extension!";
}
```